# SqlDataAdapter Update not saving

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two functions, first to get table from DB, the second to update the db. but it doesn't update the table in DB. What is wrong?

```
static SqlDataAdapter da;
static public DataTable GetTableForModify(string sql)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
        OpenCon();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
        da.Fill(dt);
        CloseCon();
    return dt;
}

static public bool SaveTable(DataTable dt)
{


    if (dt != null)
    {
        OpenCon();
        SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
        da.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
        da.Update(dt);

        CloseCon();
    }
    return true;
```

}

**Update:**
I tried this function without static parameter

Comment: Have you tried tracing this? Have you tried removing `SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);  da.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();`?

Comment: Your use of a static `da` is very odd and likely the source of your problem.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain, I tried it without success